# How to recover a number sequence just used ?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, unlock, number-sequence

I have a simple question, I don't know if It's possible.

In my *class* I have a some methods, In one in particular I create a record in **LedgerJournalTable** and save the table reference in *global* variable _createdLedgerJournalTable.

So, in another method called after there is the possibility that I **delete** my *createdLedgerJournalTable* just created.

```
LedgerJournalTable deletedLedgerJournalTable ;
ttsBegin;
select forUpdate LedgerJournalTable 
where LedgerJournalTable .RecId == _createdLedgerJournalTable;

LedgerJournalTable .delete();
ttsCommit;
```

I know it's strange I can retrieve the Part Number of deleted records ?

Begin I delete teh record I can save the *JournalNum* and mark the number sequence is NOT used?

I have seen some examples of that is used mark the number sequence ([example seen](http://theaxapta.blogspot.it/2013/06/generate-next-number-sequence-by-x-code.html)) , I can unlock the number sequence ?

Thanks in advice,

enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

If at all possible, avoid creating the journal header if you do not need it.
For example create it just before the first insert of the journal line. Test `if (!journalTable)`.

You *can* achieve what specify by calling `newGetNum` with the second parameter *_makeDecisionLater* set to true. Then call `numberSeq.abort()` to abort the number generation or `numberSeq.use()` to mark used.

This only works if in the same transaction scope as `newGetNum` and if the number sequence is continuous. if not, both calls are no-operations.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution for a non-continuous sequence. Overwritting the delete method of the datasource. This could also be implemented in the delete method of the table:

```
public void delete()
{
    NumberSequenceTable numSeqTable;
    CMT_RutaId          tmpRutaId;
    ;

    tmpRutaId = CMT_RutaJour.RutaId;
    numSeqTable = NumberSequenceTable::find(SalesParameters::numRefCMT_RutaId().NumberSequence);

    super();

    if (numSeqTable.Continuous)
    {
        // Por si se decide marcar la secuencia como contínua, liberamos el número
        NumberSeq::release(SalesParameters::numRefCMT_RutaId().NumberSequence, tmpRutaId);
    }
    else
    {
        // Si el registro que estamos eliminando es el último que hemos insertado, recuperamos el número
        if (NumberSeq::numInsertFormat(numSeqTable.NextRec - 1, numSeqTable.Format) == tmpRutaId)
        {
            ttsbegin;
            numSeqTable = NumberSequenceTable::find(numSeqTable.NumberSequence, true);
            numSeqTable.NextRec--;
            numSeqTable.doUpdate();
            ttscommit;
        }
    }
}
```

And overwritting the close method of the form, to cover the case if the user exits the form without saving the record:

```
public void close()
{;
    if (CMT_RutaJour.RutaId && !CMT_RutaJour.RecId)
        CMT_RutaJour_ds.delete();

    super();
}
```